# Query over R installation

Tags: r

I have started using R recently, I faced few issues when using R package XLConnect, i am getting error while installing the packages, I checked on internet that my java is of version x86 implying its 32 bit , but unknowingly while installing the R from cran i deleted the desktop icon of 32 bit R. So I dont know whether its just the shortcut of 32 Bit R has been deleted or the whole 32 bit R software has been deleted.

Please suggest what could I do in this scenario.

Another question is if I want to upgrade the current version of R, then how to do that.

Comment: What version of R do you have? Are you on windows? Look in the folder where the application lies, like `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0\bin\` for version 3.5. There would be a folder for `i386` and `x64` for the 32-bit and 64-bit versions respectively if they are installed. If you want a new version of R, just download and install it. The different versions sit side-by-side and do not replace each other. You can have as many different versions of R installed at the same time as you want.

Comment: Yes, thanks I was going through the CRAN and found exactly what you suggested and now R is working fine.